# Filtering sparse matrix

Tags: performance-tuning, sparse-arrays

I am interested in filtering a sparse matrix, where the values are between zero and one. I do it in the following manner.

```
s = SparseArray[RandomInteger[{1, 20}, {5, 2}] -> RandomReal[1, 5]]
fs = Select[s["NonzeroValues"], # > 0.5 &]; // AbsoluteTiming
fs
```

But I little bit confused by the result, I didn't get a sparse matrix (in the documentation written in an unclear way when `Select` return not sparse matrix [Select documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html)). Also, I am interesting to improve a runtime

Comment: Neither do I get why you expect to get a sparse matrix from `Select` nor what your issues with the runtime are. What is the output that you actually want?

Comment: Maybe `SparseArray[Subtract[1, UnitStep[Subtract[0.5, s]]]]` is what you look for...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, please take a look to subsection "Generalizations & Extensions" in the Select documentation, you will find a two example. In my opinion, there are not consistent because in one case filtering of Sparse matrix give the Sparse matrix and in the second case filtering provides the list.

Comment: Well, the first example uses `EvenQ` which embraces the background value (`0`) of the spare array. That's why the output is created as sparse vector with the same background value. In the second example, it is clear that the background value is ruled out so that there is some good reason to make the return value a dense, packed vector (a dense vector is the most appropriate data type for such data). But when you apply `Select` to `s["NonzeroValues"]`, which is a dense array, then you will of course gain a dense array as return value.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher you are right.  In my case, I can replace the default value with the Infinity and filter the matrix and after the filtering return zero as the default value.

Comment: Erm. You could do that. But why? Once again: _What do you really want to achieve?_

Comment: I want to delete from the matrix all the values that less than 0.5

Comment: @Kiril, "delete" or transform to `0` (background value)? What should be dimensions of the resulting object?

Comment: @kglr I did not explain myself correctly, I mean transform and not delete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Clip`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip.html):

```
s = SparseArray[RandomInteger[{1, 20}, {5, 2}] -> RandomReal[1, 5]];
s2 = Clip[s, {0.5, 1}];

Through[{Min, Max, Mean, StandardDeviation}[Flatten@Normal@s]]    
(* {0, 0.994525, 0.00418259, 0.058275} *)

Through[{Min, Max, Mean, StandardDeviation}[Flatten@Normal@s2]]    
(* {0.5, 0.994525, 0.501648, 0.0285514} *)
```

The referenced documentation page does not explicitly state that `Clip` can be used on sparse arrays, but, well, `SparseArray` is one of the data structures `Clip` tries to handle efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Clip` also with `∞`.

```
Clip[s, {0.5, ∞}, {0., 0.}]
```

If you want to erase the the remove entries also from the sparsity pattern of the matrix, you have to wrap with `SparseArray`:

```
SparseArray[Clip[s, {0.5, ∞}, {0., 0.}]]
```